# Maximum occurrences in a list

Tags: python, pandas, find-occurrences

I have a data frame like the one below.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['2022/09/01', '2022/09/02', '2022/09/03', '2022/09/04', '2022/09/05','2022/09/01', '2022/09/02', '2022/09/03', '2022/09/04', '2022/09/05','2022/09/01', '2022/09/02', '2022/09/03', '2022/09/04', '2022/09/05'],
        'Runner': ['Runner A', 'Runner A', 'Runner A', 'Runner A', 'Runner A','Runner B', 'Runner B', 'Runner B', 'Runner B', 'Runner B','Runner C', 'Runner C', 'Runner C', 'Runner C', 'Runner C'],
        'Training Time': ['less than 1 hour', 'less than 1 hour', 'less than 1 hour', 'less than 1 hour', '1 hour to 2 hour','less than 1 hour', '1 hour to 2 hour', 'less than 1 hour', '1 hour to 2 hour', '2 hour to 3 hour', '1 hour to 2 hour ', '2 hour to 3 hour' ,'1 hour to 2 hour ', '2 hour to 3 hour', '2 hour to 3 hour']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have counted the occurrence for each runner using the below code

```
s = df.groupby(['Runner','Training Time']).size()
s
```

The result is like below.
[image: Each Runner]

And when I use below code to get the max occurence.

```
df = s.loc[s.groupby(level=0).idxmax()].reset_index().drop(0,axis=1)
df
```

Result
[image: Max Occurrence]

The problem is on Runner B. It should show "1 hour to 2 hour" and "less than 1 hour". But now it only shows ""1 hour to 2 hour"

How can I fix the issue? Thanks.
Expected Result
[image: Expected Result]

Comment: i think you jusr want groupby runner ... not training time

Comment: But I want to find out the max occurrence of daily training hours each runner in this time period

Comment: My result for Runner A and Runner C is perfect.
The problem is Runner B -->when there are same occurrences for two items, how can I be alerted ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thsi is the best i could come up with ... its kind of gross

```
def agg_most_common(vals):
    print("vals")
    matches = []
    for i in collections.Counter(vals).most_common():
        if not matches or matches[0][1] == i[1]:
            matches.append(i)
        else:
            break
    return [x[0] for x in matches]

print(df.groupby('Runner')['Training Time'].agg(agg_most_common))
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Not showing Max occurrence result.

Comment: @PJL I misunderstood what you were asking ... i think i corrected it

Comment: Thanks Joran. I get the message --name 'collections' is not defined. Believe I have lost somewhere.

Comment: `import collections`  should solve that

Comment: Let me try tomorrow , will comment thanks

Comment: For the output it is perfect but if export to excel, seems not working, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['2022/09/01', '2022/09/02', '2022/09/03', '2022/09/04', '2022/09/05','2022/09/01', '2022/09/02', '2022/09/03', '2022/09/04', '2022/09/05','2022/09/01', '2022/09/02', '2022/09/03', '2022/09/04', '2022/09/05'],
        'Runner': ['Runner A', 'Runner A', 'Runner A', 'Runner A', 'Runner A','Runner B', 'Runner B', 'Runner B', 'Runner B', 'Runner B','Runner C', 'Runner C', 'Runner C', 'Runner C', 'Runner C'],
        'Training Time': ['less than 1 hour', 'less than 1 hour', 'less than 1 hour', 'less than 1 hour', '1 hour to 2 hour','less than 1 hour', '1 hour to 2 hour', 'less than 1 hour', '1 hour to 2 hour', '2 hour to 3 hour', '1 hour to 2 hour ', '2 hour to 3 hour' ,'1 hour to 2 hour ', '2 hour to 3 hour', '2 hour to 3 hour']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
s = df.groupby(['Runner', 'Training Time'], as_index=False).size()
s.columns = ['Runner', 'Training Time', 'Size']

r = s.groupby(['Runner'], as_index=False)['Size'].max()

df_list = []
for index, row in r.iterrows():
    temp_df = s[(s['Runner'] == row['Runner']) & (s['Size'] == row['Size'])]
    df_list.append(temp_df)

df_report = pd.concat(df_list)
print(df_report)
    
df_report.to_csv('report.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Yes looks good in the output but when I export to excel, it only las last two rows, ie header and Runner C only. Any idea I can export all the runners?

Comment: Saved the df_report in a CSV file, please check the edited answer.

Comment: Yes run again. This code is perfect. sorry for misunderstanding just now